# Removal of User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: user-profile

I am seeking instructions or howto to completely remove user profile synchronization service from single server install of SharePoint 2013 to start fresh as I am unable to move past the "starting" stage or resolve my issues following Harber's documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have already done that and reinstalled, my issue is with the synchronization as its stuck on "starting" and I would like to start fresh on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nothing important in the User Profile Service Application, just delete it.  You can do that from the Service Applications page in Central Administration.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As John indicated, just delete the UPA, then stop the Service Instance.

```
Stop-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Synchronization Service"}
```